# How to add a class to a Yii form label?

Tags: forms, yii, label

To generate the following markup:

```
<label class="foo">Bar</label>
```

The PHP will look something like:

```
<?php echo $form->label($model,'username'); ?>
```

Seems like it should be part of the htmlOptions parameter to label(), but I couldn't really figure it out.

From Yii's doc:

```
public string label(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

Ref:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#label-detail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the doc says, $htmlOptions is an array of additional HTML attributes.  The keys are the attribute, while the values are the attribute values, so to add a class attribute to the label:

```
<?php echo $form->label( $model,'username', array('class'=>'className') ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't really find a good example elsewhere, this makes sense now.

Comment: Look at CActiveForm and CHtml class of yii framework which are at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm. And look at parameters of the label function, it will solve your problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add class into PHP form class using setLabelAttribute, example:

```
<?php
class Login extends Yp_Form_Abstract
{

    public function init()
    {
...
        $username = new Yp_Form_Element(Yp_Form_Element::FIELD_textField, 'username', $this);
        $username->setLabel('Username');
        $username->setLabelAttribute('class', 'some-class');
    }
}
```